# I need to make my partitions into a single one after a failed bootcamp, how do i do this?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I am a complete novice when it comes to macs. I recently tried to use bootcamp to run windows 10 and partition part of my hard drive. I used the bootcamp assistant and I followed all of the steps but when It came to the formatting bit whilst installing windows somehow it went tits up. Now I can't re-do bootcamp because of all of these partitions. i have tried disk utility but to no avail the '-' is always greyed out and I can't resize them using the partition pie chart. I have trawled the internet for days now trying to figure out a way to put them all back into a single partition to retry the whole bootcamp procedure. Its a 2015 27" 5k mac. It is is literally driving me insane.

[image: Heres what my partitions look like]

I did go into diskutil in terminal but I couldn't workout how to copy and paste the text from that into here!!!

Any help would be appreciated massively.

Comment: Does bootcamp have an option to remove Windows? Or is it stuck as it was before?

Comment: No because windows was never properly installed, it says something along the lines of The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition.

Comment: Is it possible you backup all your OS X information, repartition the disk to one partition using the Erase tab, then reinstall OS X, then install Windows using Bootcamp? I know some people don't really have hard drives to backup to.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by booting through internet recovery command+option+r and run disk utility. I was able to delete 3 partitions and after reboot i was now able to run bootcamp assistant once again.

Comment: Yeah i tried that but the '-' button is just greyed out so i can't get rid of it?!